# Laravel Form Button Cancel

Tags: laravel

Using Laravel, I have a form and I want to include a "cancel" button that just redirects back to a different route. Since the button is within the form element, when clicked it attempts to submit the form. In the Laravel docs I don't see a good way to do this. Any suggestions or would using Javascript be best?

Thanks,

```
<div class="form-group pull-right">
    <a href="{{ route('home') }}"><button class="btn btn-default btn-close">Cancel</button></a>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-global">Register</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`<a>` elements in bootstrap can have the `btn` class and they will look just like a button, so you can take the button out and just have cancel be a link:

```
 <div class="form-group pull-right">
     <a class="btn btn-default btn-close" href="{{ route('home') }}">Cancel</a>
     <button type="submit" class="btn btn-global">Register</button>
 </div>
```

Comment: Works now. Must have just been an issue with nesting the <button> tag within the <a> tag. Thanks for helping me Jeff...yet again!

Answer (score 8):

Though it's a very late answer, But it might help others.

You can just redirect back where you have come from. Simply use the following code.

```
<a href="{{url()->previous()}}" class="btn btn-default">Cancel</a>
```

It will send you back where you have came.

Comment: Simple and elegant. Although.... if you have validation, then you can have this scenario. Submit form > errors are shown > click cancel > goes back to plain input form and now you are stuck here.

Answer (score 0):

it does not have to do with laravel. You can simple use `formaction` attribute
`<input type=submit formaction="anotherpage">`

```
<button class="btn btn-default btn-close" formaction="{{ route('home') }}">Cancel</button>
```